# bound sum with parameter , revisited

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

I need to prove (to be more precise: would like to understand why)

that it is sufficient for $g$ to be $|g(x)|\le \frac{c}{(1+|s|)^\gamma}$ with $\gamma > 1$
in order for 
 $$\beta(s) = \sup_{0\le x \le t_0} {\sum_{n\ne 0}{|g(x-nt_0)||g(x-nt_0+s)|}}$$ 
 (sum is over $n\in\mathbb{Z}$) to decay at least as fast as $(1+|s|)^{-(1+\varepsilon)}$ with $\varepsilon > 0 $

decay condition could be written as 
 $ \sup_{s\in \mathbb{R}} {(1+|s|)^{-(1+\varepsilon)}\beta(s)} = C_\varepsilon  < \infty$

or that for all $s$
 $ \beta(s)< C(1+|s|)^{-(1+\varepsilon)} $ where $C$ does not depend on $s$

(end of question) extra notes:

Here is the source in case I made mistake in typing and similar:

question is about clarifying  prop 3.4.1 page 82-83 from "ten lectures on wavelets". there is similar version in
 https://services.math.duke.edu/~ingrid/publications/ieee36-1990.pdf
T2.5 page 18-19 but there $\varepsilon$ is $1/2$ and $(1+x^2)^{-1/2}$ is used instead of $(1+|x|)^{-1}$. conditions in book are slightly stronger, doesn't look like it changes something in proof dramatically.

all this is needed to show that
 $\sum_{k\ne 0} {[\beta(\frac{2\pi}{\omega_0}k)\beta(\frac{2\pi}{\omega_0}k)]^{1/2}}$ 
 converges and that it tends to $0$ when $\omega_0 \to 0$ which is clear when we have decay condition on $\beta(s)$

I tried posting similar question but it didn't receive enough attention. If it helps I noticed that
 for $x-nt_0\ge 0$ and $x-nt_0 \ge -2s$ and $s\ge 0$ we have $|x-nt_0+s|>|s|$ , so we can take infinite 
 part of the sum and take $(1+|s|)^-\gamma$ in front, what remains is convergent sum, so that part is ok. It is similar for $s\le0$.
 but we are left with finite part 
$\sum_{n=x/t_0}^{x/t_0+2s/t_0} \frac{1}{{(1+|x-nt_0|)^\gamma (1+|x-nt_0+s|)^\gamma}}$
 (we take whole part for sum index)
 since it is finite(as finite sum) and so is $(1+|s|)^-\gamma$ we could write this finite  sum as $C(1+|s|)^-\gamma$
 but this does not seem to give uniform bound on this $C$ and we cant act like in first one since $|x-nt_0+s|<|s|$, and trying to bound this finite sum for all $s$ looks to me like a starting problem.